# Topkis' Theorem

Tags: optimization, comparative-statics

Suppose my optimization problem is stated as follows

$\max\limits_x f(x,t)$

$s.t.$   $g(x,t) \leq 0$

I am interested in finding the direction $x^*$ changes with the parameter $t$. Can someone provide me a reference that describes conditions that if satisfied by $f$ and $g$ will let me answer the question of monotonicity of $x^*$ with respect to $t$?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the analysis in  **E. Silberberg's "The Structure of Economics" (2n ed. 1990)**, is illuminating, chapter 7. The fundamental comparative-statics result (for constrained and unconstrained problems) is (eq. 7-10 of the book)

$$\frac{\partial ^2 f(x^*,t)}{\partial x\partial t} \cdot \frac {\partial x^*}{\partial t} > 0$$

The matter was initially treated in **P. Samuelson's "Foundations of Economic Analysis".**

[Topkis's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topkis%27s_theorem) is a more abstract mathematical treatment that states the condition required in order to have $\partial x^*/\partial t \geq0$.